# How can i load a story file from a different folder in JBehave

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bdd, jbehave

I need to have my mystory.story file and MyStory.java in different folders. Below is my configuration,

```
@Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
        // where to find the stories
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
                // CONSOLE and TXT reporting
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats()
                                .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML));
    }

    // Here we specify the steps classes
    @Override
    public List<CandidateSteps> candidateSteps() {
        // varargs, can have more that one steps classes
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new SurveySteps())
                .createCandidateSteps();
    }
```

That is i need to use the folder structure as

```
 test
  |_config
        |_MyStory.java
  |_stories
        |_my_Story.story
```

instead of,

```
 test
  |_MyStory.java
  |_my_Story.story
```

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Are you subclassing `JunitStories`/`JunitStory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use `JUnitStory`. 
I think the only thing you have to do is to put on the classpath both directories: `test/config` and `test/stories`. The default story resolver is `org.jbehave.core.io.UnderscoredCamelCaseResolver` this will create a story path like `"org.jbehave.core.ICanLogin.java" -> "org/jbehave/core/i_can_login.story"`, and this will be loaded using the `org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath` because that's the default resource loader. Since the `src/stories` directory is on the classpath, the resource loader will find it. Note that this requires that the classes and stories are placed in the same "package", that is if the class is `com.foo.Bar` (placed in `src/config`) then you have to place the corresponding story into `com/foo/Bar.story` (in `src/stories`). This is similar to separating resource files and java files into separate folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default story path resolver, ex:

```
@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
        .useStoryPathResolver(new StoryPathResolver() {
        @Override
        public String resolve(Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass) {
            return "_stories/_my_Story.story";
        }
    })
}
```

(Of course it is better to create somewhere outside class and use it here, not anonymous).
But keep in mind that if you do so, you need also specify explicitly name of story file, reuse somehow jbehave functionality that convert 'MyClass' to 'my_class' or create your own strategy.